# Weird output of JavaScript number.toString method

Tags: javascript, type-conversion, tostring

I'm very new with JavaScript and I was trying to play around doing a function that should do some basic validation of phone numbers. I know for a professional result you should use regex but I'm just trying to practice.

While debugging and searching on the internet I understood that number.toString should have radex specified to base 8 in order to return the number in human readeable form (maybe a bad expression but you'll see what I mean by that). In doing so it removes starting 0s. The problem is that if i replace the 0 with any other digits (i tried 1 & 2) the toString method adds another character which I don't understand why.

e.g:

`var test=1756432173 console.log(test.toString(8).length)`

Should give a length of 10 not 11

If i do the below i get a length of 9 which makes sense

`var test=0756432173 console.log(test.toString(8).length)`

I'm running everything in VSCode using the Code Runner extension in case its relevant

Please help me understand this behavior

Comment: The question is: *why* do you think 1756432173(base 10) converted to (base 8) should be 10 characters?

Comment: *number.toString should have radex specified to base 8 in order to return the number in human readeable form* - surely you want want a radix of 10 to be "human readable"?   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString   It's not clear if you understand what "base 8" is...

Comment: Easiest way to understand why it's 11 and not 10 is to do: `var test=1756432173; console.log(test.toString(8))` so that you can see the conversion result.   I'd also suggest that you try substantially simpler numbers, eg `var test=[1,7,8,9,10] ; test.forEach((e) => console.log(e.toString(8)))`

Comment: `15054203455`  <-  seems to be 11 characters long..

Comment: Numbers in js can be formatted *by convention* - eg, prefix a literal with `0x` means the rest is a hexadecimal number (base 16).   ie `0xf === 15`  prefix a literal with `0` means it's base 8, so `010 == 8` - so in your second case, starting with `07564` - your number is *already* in base8, so converting to base8 gives the same string (again, console.log the .toString(8) not the .length)

Comment: If your number has invalid characters, eg `092` - 9 is not valid in (base 8) - the the conversion will use base10.   So 0337 and 0338 will give *very* different actual values when converted to base10

Comment: Note: if you are validating a phone number, it's probably been input by a user - so it will likely be a string `"07654"` so you would need to convert *to* a number first rather than converting to a string.

Comment: The morale of the story, although a phone number looks like a number, for validation purposes I would suggest you treat it like a string.  ps. It doesn't mean you have to use regex either.

Comment: "*I understood that `number.toString` should have radex specified to base 8 in order to return the number in human readeable form*" - nope, that's where you went wrong. Human-readable generally means base 10 (unless you are working on byte sequences). "*In doing so it removes starting 0s*" - no, that happens when you `parseInt(str)` a string (or use `Number(str)`)

Answer (score 1):

This is because of how JavaScript interprets numbers.

1756432173 is interpreted as a decimal number by JavaScript (not base 8). When you call toString(8) on it, it converts this decimal number to an octal representation, which is longer in this case.

You can copy and paste this code into the browser console to see it for yourself:

```
let num = 1756432173;
let numAsBase8 = num.toString(8); // '15054203455' (length is 11)
```

In your second example, 0756432173 is interpreted as a base 8 number (because it starts with 0). When you call toString(8) on it, it simply converts this octal number to a string, which doesn't change its length.

Answer (score 0):

`Number.prototype.toString` accepts one parameter which is the radix, like you said this value determines how the number is interpreted, that is in which base it is

Base 2 is binary
Base 8 is octal
Base 16 is hexadecimal.

the function accepts values between 2 and 36 as radix.
the value defaults to 10, decimal number system.

in here you are using 8 as radix which is octal and NOT human readable, we use decimal system ie 10. so the number is first converted to its octal form and then to a string which gives you a different result than what was expected

```js
let num = 1756432173;


console.log(`octal: ${num.toString(8)}`);
console.log(`decimal: ${num.toString(10)}`);
```